# RethinkDB: How can I perform several aggregation operations by running only one query?

Tags: rethinkdb

For a table with the following results (not necessarily records with ids):
`[{time: 4, votes: 10}, {time: 6, votes: 3} ... ]`

How can I get the following result (or similar):
`{average_time: 5, total_votes: 13}`
by running only ONE query and not two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce to perform multiple aggregations. This should work

```
r.table('data').map(function(doc) {
  return {
    total_votes: doc("votes"),
    total_time: doc("times"),
    count: 1
  }
}).reduce(function(left, right) {
  return {
    total_votes: left("total_votes").add(right("total_votes")),
    total_time: left("total_time").add(right("total_time")),
    count: left("count").add(right("count"))
  }
}).map(function(result) {
  return {
    total_votes: result("total_votes"),
    average_time: result("total_time").div(result("count"))
  }
})
```

Comment: Is it just me or the current use of reduce() is not compatible with v1.12.5?

Comment: It should work the same way on 1.12 and 1.14 as far as I know. What's the problem you get? Ping me at michel@rethinkdb.com if you want.

Comment: I got back to this issue only now. Can I ask your opinion about Masatoshi's way below?

Answer (score 1):

try this :)

```
r.object(
    'average_time',
    r.table('data')('time').avg(),
    'total_votes',
    r.table('data')('votes').sum()
)
```

Comment: Is this approach 2n or n..?

Comment: only 1. it can simultaneously at once.
try it in Rethink Data Explorer Console.

Comment: Can you supply similar solution for grouped data? I mean, average and sum for each group?